# Hystrix - stopping requests at top level if one of a sequential set of external requests fail

Tags: hystrix

Apologies if the title is not clear, I couldn't quite explain my problem in such a short sentence.

I've just started using hystrix-javanica and I have it working where I have a circuit breaker around 1 external network call.

I have another scenario that I want to cover but I'm not quite sure of the best approach.

I have a booking service for which each client request internally makes 5 sequential external network calls, each subsequent one depending on the previous.
For example, if all client requests are failing in the final 5th external network call, I want to be able to break the circuit (somewhere) and stop any requests hitting the any of the 5 external network calls, essentially closing the booking service for a period of time.

How would you see this being implemented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example from HystrixDemo that might help.

```
public void executeSimulatedUserRequestForOrderConfirmationAndCreditCardPayment() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    /* fetch user object with http cookies */
    UserAccount user = new GetUserAccountCommand(new HttpCookie("mockKey", "mockValueFromHttpRequest")).execute();

    /* fetch the payment information (asynchronously) for the user so the credit card payment can proceed */
    Future<PaymentInformation> paymentInformation = new GetPaymentInformationCommand(user).queue();

    /* fetch the order we're processing for the user */
    int orderIdFromRequestArgument = 13579;
    Order previouslySavedOrder = new GetOrderCommand(orderIdFromRequestArgument).execute();

    CreditCardCommand credit = new CreditCardCommand(previouslySavedOrder, paymentInformation.get(), new BigDecimal(123.45));
    credit.execute();
}
```

This method has five commands out of the which some are dependent on each other but if any of them will fail the method is exit with an exception.

I hope this helps.